# Cannot install matplotlib in cygwin (freetype issue)

Tags: windows, 64-bit, cygwin, pip, matplotlib

It would be really nice to have matplotlib in my cygwin environment. I have 64-bit Windows 8 with 64-bit cygwin.

When I type:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

I get whe following error message:

```
 * The following required packages can not be built:
 * freetype
```

As per apt-cyg I have following packages already installed:

```
Searching for installed packages matching freetype: 
cygwin32-freetype2
freetype2-debuginfo
libfreetype-devel
libfreetype-doc
libfreetype6
```

What else does it need? How to install freetype & matplotlib properly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem on Windows 7 64-bit; I solved it by installing the Cygwin packages `pkg-config` and `libX11-devel` before typing `easy_install matplotlib==1.1.1` (the 1.3.1 version is having errors on my machine, hence the 1.1.1).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I'll try it. As for me, I just use matplotlib outside cygwin (normal Windows installation).

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same problem on cygwin Windows 8 64-bit. I followed the advice in another response (install `pkg-config` and `libX11-devel`) but the package that finally allowed me to install matplotlib was `libfreetype-devel`. Then just `easy_install matplotlib==1.4.2`.